# How to unit-test the interaction of an Angular Service with $cookies?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, cookies, karma-runner, angularjs-service

I currently have a service that is depending on a variable set in $cookies. However, when I want to unit test the interaction between the service and the value stored in $cookies, then the service is always initialized before the actual initialization of the $cookie value.

So, my question is: how can I unit-test the interaction between the service and the $cookie value properly? (e.g.: how can I set the value in $cookies before my service is initialized?)

Note: I am using Angular 1.2 and Karma for unit testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I found, which works with services (as opposed to controllers), is to use a decorator on `$cookieStore` during the module set up in the `beforeEach`.

anagular-mocks let us configure our modules in the specs in a similar way as we do in the code, except that instead of using the `config` function, we pass a function as a second argument to the `module` function we use to invoke our module in jasmine.

It would look like this:

```
describe ('my service', function () {
    var $cookieStore,
        myService

    beforeEach(module ('myModule', function ($provide) {
        // this function configures the "myModule" module before any
        // injectables are created.

        // We use a decorator to access the cookie store before other
        // services are instantiated.
        $provide.decorator ('$cookieStore', function ($delegate) {
            // at this point the "$cookieStore" service  has only just 
            // been constructed, and is accessible here as "$delegate".
            // Services that have "$cookieStore" as an injected
            // dependency have not been instantiated yet, so we
            // can slip our cookie in now.
            $delegate.put ('favorite-cookie', 'oatmeal');
            return $delegate;
        });
    }));

    beforeEach (inject (function (_$cookieStore_, _myService_) {
        myService = _myService;
        $cookieStore = _$cookieStore_;
    }

    it ('should interact with the pre-existing "favorite-cookie" cookie', function () {
        // your expectations go here.
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        // clean up
        $cookieStore.remove ('favorite-cookie');
    });


});
```

Answer (score 6):

I created an example in JSFiddle which I hope helps you with your problem.

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/QAQmy/)

```
//--- CODE --------------------------
angular.module('myapp.test', [], function () {

}).controller('testcont', function($scope, $cookies) {
    // Read a cookie and do something with it
    $scope.favoriteCookie = $cookies.myFavorite;
});

// --- SPECS -------------------------

describe('controllers', function(){
  var scope;   
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ngCookies', 'myapp.test'));   
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $cookies){    
    // Setting a cookie for testing
    $cookies.myFavorite = 'oatmeal';
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
      $controller('testcont', {$scope:scope, $cookies: $cookies});
  }));

  it('sets the cookie on the scope', function(){
      expect(scope.favoriteCookie).toBe('oatmeal');      
  });
});
```

Comment: hi can you explain why using $cookies: $cookies? why it doesn't $cookies: cookies like $scope:scope. why don't there have $rootScope.$new() like operetaion?

Comment: The property key is the name of the injectable component, e.g. "$scope". The property value is the injected instance. In the case above I injected $cookies to the function, so I used that as the injected instance. It's simply a matter of naming the vars used as instances

Comment: The issue was regarding services. The proposed answer addresses controllers, but not services. Controllers are relatively easy to instantiate, since you supply the constructor. Services are harder, because there is no easily accessible constructor. Angular instantiates them inside the provider.